# Applet: connect to other host

Tags: java, applet

Hallo,

Now, in my one site applet loads from A host and it should work with
B host. But When I tried to do it I got

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission MY_URL:443 connect,resolve)

exception. Applet is signed. I have added crossdomain.xml to B host too, but it is not help.

Are there any solution of this issue?

crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- http://192.168.0.199/crossdomain.xml -->
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="Authorization,X-HTTP-Method-Override"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a solution. An applet is allowed to contact only the server that it has been downloaded from. Regards, - M.S.

Comment: this is misleading answer, have a look at an example http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/05/28/java-doodle-crossdomainxml-support

Comment: Nice article, Osw. I did not know about it, thanks for the info. @OP: I take my answer back, please point to the above article and carry on. Later, - M.S.